# Bean definitions and attributes. Its usage in Spring Hibernate and Maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

```
<bean id="methodNameResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver">
    <property name="paramName">
        <value>act</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am a beginner in spring mvc application developer and i found this code somewhere and i can't understand it properly 
and i also wants some references for learn spring mvc and bean attributes which are used by developers most commonly

Comment: thanks to all for their guide lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just say set the value "act" to the property "paramName" in ParameterMethodNameResolver class.

Eg : The format of the class ParameterMethodNameResolver  should be as follow.

```
class ParameterMethodNameResolver{  
String paramName;
 .
 .
}
```

Anyway better to read spring documentation first. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

I think this is better too
http://websystique.com/spring-4-mvc-tutorial/

Happy learning. Thanks

Comment: thank you @isurujay your answer will become usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

## Look at the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/ParameterMethodNameResolver.html):

> Implementation of `MethodNameResolver` which supports several strategies
>   for mapping parameter values to the names of methods to invoke.
>
> The simplest strategy looks for a specific named parameter, whose
>   value is considered the name of the method to invoke. The name of the
>   parameter may be specified as a JavaBean property, if the default
>   action is not acceptable.

## The [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-parametermethodnameresolver-example/):

> `ParameterMethodNameResolver`, a `MultiActionController` method name
>   resolver to map URL to method name via request parameter name, and the
>   parameter name is customizable through the `paramName` property.

Comment: thanx for reply @nikpon. But, i hve already read same answer on some web page.